# Limit to infinity of recurrence relation

Tags: limits, number-theory, functions, recurrence-relations

Looking at some recurrence relations such as $a_{n+1}=\frac{(1-a_n)}{2}$ the limit as $n$ tends to infinity can be solved by solving $x=\frac{(1-x)}{2}$. My question is whether a similar method can be used with:$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{\operatorname{gcd}(2^{a_n},a_n)}+1$$
When $a_{0}$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a_n) $ be defined by
$$a_0\in I \;\text{where I is an interval }$$
$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N)\;\;a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$$
The sequence will be well defined if $ f(I)\subset I$.

If $ I $ is closed, and $ \lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=L $ and $ f $ is continuous at $ L $ THEN
$$f(L)=L$$

In your case, the function does not seem to be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

You have a sequence of integers.  So it can converge only if it is eventually constant.  That is, it can converge to $L$ only if
$$
L=\frac{L}{\operatorname{gcd}(2^{L},L)}+1
\tag1$$
So in this case, your answer is YES.
Note $(1)$ means $L=2$.  So **if** your sequence converges, then it converges to $2$.  However, this argument does not show that it does converge.  For that, argue that $a_{n+1} < a_n$ if $a_n > 2$.